# Sharepoint: Remove Quicklaunch, Show Library Metadata Navigation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to replace the quick launch menu on the left hand side of just one library in a SharePoint 2013 site. Instead, I would like to show just the library metadata navigation.

Is there a way to do this without modifying the master? If not, is there a way to move the navigation above the menu? I tried some code in the script editor I found on a different site, but I just made everything disappear! I also tried just removing the menu, but the entire bar disappeared including the metadata navigation.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who finds this question, adding the below snippet to a script editor webpart on the library page solved my issue:

```
 <style>
 .ms-core-listmenu-verticalBox{ DISPLAY: none }
 </style>
```